# Why does the function composition of two "not" functions in CL result in nil according to this book?

Tags: common-lisp, negation

I am studying the book **Common LISP: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation**. The book is around 40 yrs old and, apparently, somewhat a classic.

In chapter 1, the author uses boxes as a way of explaining functions with inputs and outputs. This is one of the drawings:
[image]

Actually, the drawing above is the **answer** of this question. I got the first and the second question wright:
[image]

However, the third question seems weird:
[image]

The composition of (not (not ...)) depends on the "..." variable part.
For instance, the terminal shows:

```
CL-USER> (not (not 12))
T
CL-USER> (not (not nil))
NIL
```

This book exercise seems wrong in some way. But, since I do not know much about CL I thought it would be better to ask if more experienced developer in CL also think this is a strange point in the answer sheet.

I am using SBCL, Slime and Common Lisp. I am new to CL but I have some experience in Racket.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exercise 1.14:

Actually the author wants us to use the symbol `NOT` as an input to the function `NOT`. The input is not the function named `NOT` and also not the variable named `NOT`. Thus the symbol needs to be quoted in a computation:

```
> (NOT 'NOT)
NIL
```

Since every symbol is *true*, not of *true* is *false*. *false* in Common Lisp is the symbol `NIL`.

What is different between the symbols `NIL` and `NOT` ?

- `NIL` evaluates to itself
- `NOT` has no default value and evaluates as a variable. To evaluate the symbol `NOT` to itself, it needs to be quoted.

This is explained in chapter *3.8 USING SYMBOLS AND LISTS AS DATA* in the old edition.

Comment: ah right, makes total sense. (never believe an OP's statement without checking!) if only they'd included the preceding example of `FRED --> [ NOT ] --> NIL`, it'd be that much clearer.  it's so early in the book, where it still only deals with symbols and numbers...

Answer (score 3):

The exercise is not showing composition of functions; it is showing the application of the function `not` to the argument `not`. In Common Lisp all values are true except for `nil` (and `'nil`, `()`, and `'()`), so applying `not` to `not` must evaluate to `nil`.

There is a caveat: [`not` is a function in Common Lisp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_not.htm), but there are multiple name spaces in CL. If you want to try this in the REPL, you will have to specify that you mean the *function* `not`, not the *variable* `not` by using either `function` or `#'` (sharp-quote):

```
CL-USER> (not (function not))
NIL
CL-USER> (not #'not)
NIL
CL-USER> (not not)  ; --> The variable NOT is unbound.
```

Hmmm. Some of us were too lazy to actually look up the exercise in the book; it appears that at this point in the book only numbers and symbols have been discussed (duh!). The author's intention was that `not` be a symbol, which means that it must be quoted in a function call.

Since `not` is a *function*, it evaluates its arguments. The call `(not not)` evaluates the argument `not`, but `not` is an unbound variable so an error is issued. To pass the *symbol* `not` to the *function* `not`, the argument must be quoted either with `quote` (which is *not* a function, but a *special operator*: `quote` does not evaluate its arguments) or a quote mark (`'`). The quoted `not` evaluates to a symbol:

```
CL-USER> not  ;  -->  The variable NOT is unbound.
CL-USER> (quote not)
NOT
CL-USER> 'not
NOT
CL-USER> (symbolp 'not)
T
CL-USER> (not 'not)
NIL
```

Since `nil` is the only symbol that is false in a boolean context, the symbol `not` must be true, so `(not 'not)` must be false.

Comment: Thanks. I tried CL-USER> (not not)  ; --> The variable NOT is unbound. I thought there was no way to fix it. Did not know about the #' . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a composition. It is a function call

```
(not not)
```

The function `not` receives a value, which is the function `not`, as its argument. Since this value is not `NIL`, the return value is `NIL`:

```
not:
--------------------
NIL      --->   T           (not NIL)
non-NIL  --->   NIL         (not T), (not 1), (not not), (not (list 1)), ...
--------------------
```

Any non-`NIL` value is truthy, so `not` returns a `NIL` for it.

Of course `(not not)` works in Scheme which is Lisp-1. In Common Lisp which is Lisp-2, the call is `(not #'not)`.

*update:* the call is actually `(not 'not)`, just as the preceding example's code in the book is `(not 'fred)`.